# How do i set the apex (intercept) when scaling

Tags: d3.js

Lets assume this is the d3 code

```js
this.y = d3
    .scalePow()
    .exponent(2)
    .domain([2000, 10000])
    .range([600, 0]);
```

What it does is mapping 2000 to 600, 10000 to 0, and everything inbetween is scaled by some quadratic formula which has its apex at 2000. Now the question is easy, how to i set the apex to say 6000? i want detailed values (big gaps) in the 6000 and narrow steps in the outer rim.

I added a picture i drew with my fingers for clarificarion. I might add a better pic later[image]

I am not sure if parabola apex is the right word, in german its called Scheitelpunkt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want can be done using a [Symlog scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/main/README.md#symlog-scales), which provides a bi-symmetric log transformation.

For that to work, what you call the *apex* (that is, `6000`) will be the zero in the scale, and the domain will be `[-4000, 4000]` (since `2000 = 6000 - 4000`, and `10000 = 6000 + 4000`).

Also, don't forget to format the ticks, adding `6000`, and obviously the values you pass to the scale as well.

Here's the demo:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width", 600);

const scale = d3.scaleSymlog()
  .constant(500)
  .range([20, 580])
  .domain([-4000, 4000]);

const axis = d3.axisBottom(scale).tickFormat(d => d + 6000);

svg.append("g").attr("transform", `translate(0,${50})`).call(axis)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: This looks good, can you add some information about what `.constant()` does? The `500` seems random. Or is it like the the width of the detailed part?

Comment: I think i can do the same thing with scalePow, it writes here that its also symmetrical - https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#power-scales `Power scales also support negative domain values, in which case the input value and the resulting output value are multiplied by -1.` - But maybe the log fits my needs better

Answer (score 0):

Simply, change the `.exponent(2)` to `.exponent(1/2)`:

[image]

This has everything to do with the fact that `x^2` and `sqrt(x)` are inverse functions.

[image]

Comment: I added a picture for clarification, thank u for your help!